# Divide points in matrix with one line

Tags: algorithm, matrix

lets say I have a 2D matrix/map. In this matrix I place points of two types(type A, type B). I want to find out, if it is possible to divide type A and type B points in matrix with one single line. Im looking for algorithms or ideas how to solve this problem. Any advice is appreiated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want *a line* or do you want *yes/no* as the answer?

Comment: i only need a yes/no answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the convex hull of each group (Type A and Type B), if the hulls don't intersect you can separate them with a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a binary [linear classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier).

The answer is yes iff there exists a linear classifier that is *consistent* with the training set (i.e. the classifier is giving the correct label for each point in the training set, which is your data).

[Perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) is one simple way to achieve a linear classifier.
A more advanced technique (that is also achieving a better classifier) is [Support Vector Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)

Answer (score 1):

This question had a solution [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/line-separates-two-sets-of-points) that describes a very nice O(n) randomized algorithm.